# facing a problem when applying structs to save information from app

Tags: swift, xcode, struct

```
let questions = ["____ Book","File ____"]
let answers = [["Read","Heed","Write","Say"],["lawsuit", "acquisition", "care","office"]]
var answerDict:[String:[Int:Any]] = [String:[Int:Any]]()
var answerChosen:[String] = [String]()



// variables
// keeps track of what qs we at
var currentQuestion = 0
var rightAnswerPlacement:UInt32 = 0

//var for counting number of time users press button
var ActionCount: Int = 0



//struc for parsing the qs
struct report {
    var question : String
    var AnswersChosen : [String] = [String]()
    var userCount : Int
```

Above is where I introduce the struct to my quiz app. My struct includes the current question user is on, AnswersChosen is the choices the user selected for that question before getting the correct one and lastly userCount is the number of tries he took

```
//creating array of report struct
var currentReport = [report]()
//currentReport.append(report(question:questions , AnswersChosen:[String](), userCount:0))
        
//array for what users are selecting
answerChosen.append(sender.title(for: .normal)!)
//print (answerChosen)
//currentReport.AnswersChosen = answerChosen
print(answerChosen)
        
//counting number of times wrong button is pressed
ActionCount += 1
//currentReport.userCount = ActionCount
print(ActionCount)
currentReport.append(report(question:questions[currentQuestion] , AnswersChosen:answerChosen, userCount:ActionCount))
print(currentReport)
```

This is where I write down the function and the instances of the struct. Currently, my output from this code gives me:

[image]

this is not the output I am looking for. Hence, my question is how to do I edit my code such that I am able to create a 'report' for every question and the AnswersChosen in each report are only from the current question the user is on

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter out the current question from the array first. To do this we need to first get the question from the array

```
let question = questions[currentQuestion]
```

then we filter on it by getting the first one we find from the currentReport array

```
currentReport.first(where: { $0.question == question})
```

This can actually be written in one line as

```
let current = currentReport.first(where: { $0.question == questions[currentQuestion]})
```

---

A few things about the struct, type names should start with uppercase letters and property names with lowercase. And the property userCount looks redundant since it is always the count of the number of answers chosen. So the struct could be changed to

```
struct Report {
    var question : String
    var answersChosen = [String]()
}
```